# Trying to edit a text file through my webserver hosted on my raspberry. raspberry is a hotspot and i am connected to it with my laptop

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webserver

So i have a raspberry 3 running raspberry pi os (bullseye). i am running a webserver on it with apache. The raspberry is set up as a hotspot. I am connected to it with my laptop. I have made a box which is clickable and runs a function in javascript. I want this funtion to edit a textfile which is on the raspberry. I found some information about node.js and tried reading and writing the file this way. it works when running node 'filename'.js in terminal but i cant get it to work when i press the box. This is the problem i have. i want it to edit the textfile when i press the box and not just when i use node 'filename'.js in terminal.

i read something about require('fs') doesnt work locally and i dont know how to solve this.

```js
function forwardf() {
  // Läs om variabeln är true eller false
  alert("hit kommer vi");
  document.getElementById("variabler.txt");
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    alert("hit kommer vi");

      // Entire file
      //alert(this.result);

      // By lines
      var lines = this.result('\n');
      for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        alert(lines[line]);
      }
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
  alert(text);


  /*
  //const fs = require('fs');
  //let fileString = fs.readFileSync("variabler.txt").toString();
  const line = fileString.split(/\r?\n/);
  const our_variable = line[0].split("=");
  let temp = our_variable[1];
  // Change this_var to true
  if (temp == "false") {
    //alert("temp was false");
    console.log("temp was false" + "\n");
    fileString = fileString.replace(/goforward=false/, "goforward=true");
  } 
  // else change this_var to false
  else {
    //alert("temp was true");
    console.log("temp was true" + "\n");
    fileString = fileString.replace(/goforward=true/, "goforward=false");
  }
  fs.writeFileSync("variabler.txt", fileString);
  console.log(fileString);
}
*/
```

```css
.allt {
  width:1200px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:3px;
  display:inline-flex;
}
.box {
  width:796px;
  height:690px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.karta {
  width:460px;
  height:460px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px 0px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
}
.autonomt {
  width:313px;
  height:460px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.auto {
    width:290px;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:5px;
}
.status {
  width:290px;
  height:220px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:5px;
}
.konsol {
  Width:780px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:5px 0px 0px 5px;
  text-align:center;
}
.movementbox {
    width:386px;
    height:680px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:right;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dartbox {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid white;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:4px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:scale-down;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forsta_utkast_styles.css" media="screen" />
      <script type="text/javascript"
        src="funktioner.js";>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="allt" class="allt">
      <div id="box" class="box">
        <div id="karta" class="karta">
          <h2>Karta</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="autonomt" class="autonomt">
          <div id="auto" class="auto">
            <h2>Autonomt</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="status" class="status">
            <p>b</p>
            <p>b</p>
            <p>b</p>
            <p>b</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="konsol" class="konsol">
        <h1>konsol</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="movementbox" class="movementbox">
        <div id="dartbox1" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox2" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox3" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox4" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox5" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox6" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox7" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox8" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox9" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox10" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/counter_clockwise.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="forwardbox" class="dartbox" onclick="forwardf()" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="bilder_pilar/forwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox12" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/clockwise.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox13" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/leftpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox14" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/manuell_styrning.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox15" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/rightpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox16" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/land.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox17" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/backwardpil.png" alt="fel"></div>
        <div id="dartbox18" class="dartbox"><img src="bilder_pilar/lift.png" alt="fel"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats now how any of it works.

**Here's why its not working:** *(dont ignore this, else you wont understand any of it)*

- There is frontend and there is backend.

  - Frontend is something that runs on the browser - on the user's side. This is what the user sees.
  - Backend is something that will run on the server - in this case its your Raspberry Pi.
- The file read/write code that you execute from terminal, gets executed on the backend.
- However, when you are adding the js file in HTML, the browser will try to execute it on the user's side - the frontend.

**Here's what you need to do:**

- Read what REST API is
- Implement a nodejs based REST API, which will also have the code to read/write the file
- Call the REST API from your browser, on button click. Simplest way is to use  HTML Form, and the REST API action in the form.

Good luck. Happy coding!